# How to access configmap data as environment variable inside application.properties file in Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kubernetes, configmap

I have a configmap in kubernetes declared as follows.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: common-config
  
data:
  a.properties: |
    x=abc
    y=bvt
```

I want to access key 'x' and 'y' in spring boot application.properties as environment variables as follows using my deployment.yaml file

```
application.properties
  spring.datasource.url=${x}
  spring.datasource.driver-class-name=${y}.
```

This is working if my configmap declared as follows.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: common-config
  
data:
   x=abc
   y=bvt
```

and  in deployment.yaml

```
env:
     - name: x
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              key: x
              name: common-config
        - name: y
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              key: y
              name: common-config
```

So I don't know how to access property as enviroment variable from configmap if it is under any properties file (like a.properties).

Could you please suggest the way to get it.

Comment: With ConfigMaps & valuesFrom, you can't. As you saw, with those valueFroms, at best, you can map a key of your ConfigMap as some environment variable. Kubernetes won't be able to parse ini, json or yaml within those keys, to further extract a portion of that configmap entry, as an env var. Here you may use your own entrypoint, which would implemt that logic, parsing your configmap the way you want it.

Comment: Thank you for prompt response. If I mount a.properties to a location in my pod server and using that location, can I access the properties of a.properties file in my spring boot application.properties file ?